# Connecting many proximity sensors to a controller

Tags: proximity-sensor

I need to connect many (about 100) IR proximity sensors to a controller. What are my options? Can use any sensors, for example one of those - https://ams.com/proximity

Comment: Hi, There are many different sensors listed on that page, but they all use I2C so I'll address that point. There have been several previous questions here about how to connect multiple identical I2C devices to one I2C master. I recommend searching for previous Q&A on I2C multiplexer (mux) & I2C switch (or even using analog switches for I2C) and reading those. Then you can ask a more specific question, if they still don't answer your concern. Otherwise, you're likely to get similar replies to those previous questions. With 100 sensors, bus loading, latency & addressing should be considered.

Comment: The only option appears to be either connect them or not connect them. So decide what you want and choose the option or, if in fact you have not explained yourself very well in your question, feel free to correct that oversight.

Comment: I may very well not have explained myself well. Let me check out those previous posts...